# Passando chave de dicionários como parâmetro em função integrada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com uma duvida simples em relação a utilização de dicionários em funções.
Tem alguma forma de eu passar os valores das chaves ["Idade"] dos dicionários na lista abc como parâmetro na função mean? (calcular média de uma lista)

```
import statistics as stt
abc = [{"Nome": "Joana", "Idade": 14}, {"Nome": "Fernanda", "Idade": 24}, {"Nome": "Josué", "Idade": 24}]
###abc = [2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 3, 44, 5, 3]
stt.mean(abc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função `map` para mapear a lista com os dicionários em uma lista com somente a idades e, em seguida, calcular a média.

```
import statistics as stt

pessoas = [{"Nome": "Joana", "Idade": 14},
           {"Nome": "Fernanda", "Idade": 24},
           {"Nome": "Josué", "Idade": 24}]

idades = map(lambda pessoa: pessoa['Idade'], pessoas)
avg = stt.mean(idades)

print(f"A média é: {avg}.")
```

No código acima, passamos para o [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) uma [*lambda function*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), que acessa (e retorna) a idade do dicionário de cada iteração do mapeamento.

Uma outra opção (ao `map` com *lambda*) é utilizar [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
idades = [pessoa['Idade'] for pessoa in pessoas]
avg = mean(idades)
```

A saída, para ambos os códigos, será a mesma:

```
A média é: 20.666666666666668.
```